# Convergence rate of cardinal series (Whittaker-Shannon interpolant)

Tags: reference-request, approximation-theory

Given $f \in C^{k}_{0}[a, b]\cap L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, what can we say about the convergence rate of the cardinal series
$$
s(t) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} f(a+jh) \mathrm{sinc}\left(\pi\left(\frac{t-a}{h} -j \right)\right), \quad hn = b -a
$$
to $f$ as $h\to 0$?

(Moved in desperation from [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3208974/convergence-rate-of-cardinal-series).)

Comment: Out of curiosity - is the term "cardinal series" well known for this expression? Where does it come from?

Comment: @AmirSagiv: This is the terminology from I.J. Schoenberg's 1973 book "Cardinal Spline Interpolation". It is also known as the Whittaker-Shannon interpolant.